NVL join using pandas
I want to perform a NVL join with pandas, e.g. in SQL:
select * from TA 
join TB on
 TA.column = NVL(TB.column, TA.column)

Here is a complete example in SQL, showing what would be expected:
/* first table a, with a single column "aa" :
   aa
   1
   2
   2 */
create table a as 
select 1 aa from dual
union all
select 2 aa from dual
union all
select 2 aa from dual;

/* second table b, with a single column as well:
   aa
   1
   null
   null
   4 */
create table b as 
select 1 aa from dual
union all
select null aa from dual
union all
select null aa from dual
union all
select 4 aa from dual;

following an nvl join, e.g.:
select a.aa from a join b on a.aa = nvl(b.aa, a.aa);

The result is this one:
1
1 
1
2
2
2
2

That is, every line of table a appears as many time as it exists or is null in b.
As you can see, both tables don't necesarly have the same number of rows.
I tried to use something like combine_first but it does not work.
What's the simplest & effective way to do this in pandas, if possible?
What if there are several NVL conditions?
Thanks

Please provide a [mre]. Add the data as text, not as pictures. And please also add the desired output (based on the minimal sample provided).

Set the desired key(s) as index and combine_first

@mozway no it does not work, see example of what is expected

@Carmellose thanks, it's more explicit with a example, see if the solution below works for you

Can you also clarify if you have other columns and what should happen to them?

IIUC, you can combine a classical merge and a cross-merge on the NaN rows with concat:
# merge df1/df2 on "aa"
# cross-merge the NA rows
out = (pd.concat([df1.merge(df2, on='aa'),
                  df1.merge(df2[df2['aa'].isna()].drop(columns='aa'),
                            how='cross')], ignore_index=True)
         .sort_values(by='aa', ignore_index=True) # optional
      )

Variant, replicating directly df1 the number of times you have NaNs (might be efficient enough if you have just a few NaNs).
# count the number of NAs in df2['aa']
n_na = df2['aa'].isna().sum()

# merge df1/df2 on "aa"
# and copy as many rows as there are NAs
out = (pd.concat([df1.merge(df2, on='aa')]+[df1]*n_na,
                 ignore_index=True)
         .sort_values(by='aa', ignore_index=True) # optional
      )

Output:
   aa
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   2

If you have extra columns, then the cross-merge will give you the following:
   aa  bb_x  bb_y
0   1   1.1   2.1
1   1   1.1   2.2
2   1   1.1   2.3
3   2   1.2   2.2
4   2   1.2   2.3
5   2   1.2   2.2
6   2   1.2   2.3

Alternative input:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'aa': [1,2,2], 'bb': [1.1, 1.2, 1.2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'aa': [1,None,None,4], 'bb': [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4]})

